# Is there a way to make estimated row heights with UITableView actually work with accurate scroll position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

Estimated row heights with `UITableView` are great for performance, but boy are they a headache when trying to have an accurate scroll offset with your table view.

[This article from Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) details some of the issues at the bottom. [As does this article](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/81410534498/cell-height-caching-dilemmas-in-unread). When you go to a new view controller and then return back to the table view after, the table view gets completely confused where you are and doesn't return the user to their previous location. The same can occur with rotation sometimes and even simple scrolling.

I can't help but wonder... **what is the point then**? Should it not bring you back to exactly where you were before?

I know that's difficult with estimates, but is there no way to accomplish that other than giving *perfect* estimates (which then aren't really estimates and defeat the purpose)? Because right now unless there's a single view controller with cells in it, any other situation, such as segueing to a new view controller seems to *really* mess it up.

How do I use estimates in a way that is actually useful and doesn't cause jumping all over the place?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you - a UITableView with different row heights embedded within a UIPageViewController. The TableView would scroll fine, I would swipe away and back onto the table, and the position would be all over the place.

Using both estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath is what did the trick for me, as indicated in [this article](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/16/ios7-day-by-day-day-19-uitableview-row-height-estimation). From then on, whenever I swiped away and back onto the table, the position would remain the same. Hurray!

There was still a problem though: the first time the table is loaded estimatedRowHeights only gets **the last half of the cells** (rows 16 to 31 out of 32 cells for example) and therefore makes you start in the middle. As soon as I would scroll, the first half of the cells (rows 0 to 15) would load and I would be back on row 0 instead of row 15. After that the table would behave fine.

Although a minor problem, the work-around is to simulate a scroll up once the very last cell has been loaded. This triggers the loading of the first cells and brings your table to the "proper" row 0.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return whatever the cell height should be
    return myCellsArray[indexPath.row]["height"] as CGFloat
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return whatever the cell height should be
    return myCellsArray[indexPath.row]["height"] as CGFloat
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Check that the final cell has been loaded and that this is the first time the table is loaded
    if indexPath.row == myCellsArray.count - 1 && myStruct.tableHasLoaded == false{
        // Reached the bottom
        println("bottom reached with cell \(indexPath.row)")
        // Simulate a mini scroll backwards as estimatedRowHeight only starts halfway and loads the final half, not the first half of the cells
        // This way it forces it to go back to row 0
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1), animated: false)
        // Set bool to true - we don't want to go back to the top everytime we reach the bottom of the table
        myStruct.tableHasLoaded = true
    }
}
```